# Suggestions of inexpensive PCI Video Card (fanless or very very quiet) that'll work with Windows 7 (32 bit)?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, noise

I just got a very quiet Dell Optiplex 960 (with dual monitor video card) and wanted a 3rd monitor (only a PCI slot available). The PCI video card I got has a relatively loud (compared to this quiet PC) fan.

I'm looking for a quiet card. Need not be very powerful as it's for the third screen which I don't use for video or games, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, if you want to enable Aero on it, you'll need a DirectX 9.0+ compatible graphics chip with at least 128MB ram. For the offerings available at Newegg click [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007709%20600007853%20600007813&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Order=PRICE&PageSize=20). As far as being Windows 7 supported i would say any of them would have either built in support or have drivers on Windows Update, if not on the chipset manufacturers website (nVidia or AMD).

Answer (score 2):

Get a fanless GeForce 6200

[Here's some open box ones from Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130289R&cm_re=geforce_6200-_-14-130-289R-_-Product)

Comment: I'm looking for something with a fair number of positive reviews and some indication that it works on Win7 (or at least Vista)

Comment: Nvidia's 7/Vista driver download page lists 6200 as a supported card: http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7_winvista_64bit_196.21_whql.html

Answer (score 0):

[Found one on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001E42QGM). (I'll take a look at Taspeotis' as well:

- Windows 7 compatible (one reviewer reported the Win 7 scores and says the Vista driver works for 7)
- The heat sink looks pretty substantial.
- Free Shipping from Amazon.

Comment: I prefer "mine" because it has a DVI port. Unless your monitors are 1280 x 1024 or less you will get a better picture from using DVI.

Comment: This is for an old monitor that is less than 1280x1024.  And I'd like to be sure that it'll be Win7 compatible. Also, no reviews of the other one.

Comment: This card ended up causing random memory-fault crashes (about 1 per week). Arggggg!